# SU(3) adjoint representation's invariant tensors

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, representation-theory, invariants

Considering a complex scalar field $\varphi^a$ that transform in the adjoint representation (8) of SU(3).
A quartic interaction term SU(3) invariant is

$$\lambda  C^{abcd}\varphi^{\dagger a} \varphi^{\dagger b}\varphi^{c}\varphi^{d}$$

where $C^{abcd}$ is an invariant tensor of $8\times8\times8\times8$. I know that there are 5 independent invariant tensors, i think that two could be
$$ \delta^{ac}\delta^{bd} \quad ,\quad d^{abh}d^{hcd} $$
 How i can find all invariant tensors of this product? Thanks

Comment: Ahhmm... the **8** is a real rep. Why are you conjugating the φs? And **8** ⊗ **8** yields a singlet and an **8** and a **10** and its conjugate, and a **27**. So Kronecker-squaring this yields only 3 singlets: in the **1** ⊗ **1**, the **8**  ⊗ **8** and the **27** ⊗ **27**, no? There appear no further singlets in the remaining cross terms. Which suggests you may be missing just one, not three, superficially at least.

Comment: $8\otimes 8 = 1 +8_A + 8_S + .....$ so i get 5 singlets. I think there is no problem using 8 for transform complex fields or i am wrong?

Comment: Apologies, i skipped the other **8**.  I don't think there is a problem with complex fields, but the real and imaginary parts transform separately. I suspect you could also use pure real ones. In any case, the missing term you proffer argues for *fd* type cross terms, *ff*, ....

Comment: Tomorrow i'll try with $fd$! I already proof that $ff \approxeq\delta \delta + dd$ so is not independent.

Comment: [Dittner 1971](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103857479) .